# The expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used - Flutter Dart unable to add custom object to list in for loop

Tags: list, flutter, dart, addition

I need to create a new list 'filteredSlots' which will have the slots from 'slotlist' list which has its availabilty and its consecutive slots availability is also set to true.

But I get an error for add(). Please help me resolve this

```
class Slot {
  String time;
  bool isAvailable;

  Slot({this.time, this.isAvailable});
}

class FilterSlots {
  List<Slot> slotlist = [
    Slot(time: '10:00', isAvailable: true),
    Slot(time: '10:30', isAvailable: false),
    Slot(time: '11:00', isAvailable: true),
    Slot(time: '11:30', isAvailable: true),
    Slot(time: '12:00', isAvailable: true),
    Slot(time: '12:30', isAvailable: false),
    Slot(time: '13:00', isAvailable: true),
  ];

  List<Slot> filteredSlots = [];

  List<Slot> filterSlots() {
    for (var i = 0; i < slotlist.length - 1; i++) {
      if ((slotlist[i].isAvailable) & (slotlist[i + 1].isAvailable)) {
        filteredSlots = filteredSlots.add(slotlist[i]);
      }
    }
    return filteredSlots;
  }
}

//Expected output,

List<Slot> filteredslots = [
  Slot(time: '11:00', isAvailable: true),
  Slot(time: '11:30', isAvailable: true),
];
```

Comment: why dont you use [List.where](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) method?

Comment: please can you explain me how to use that for my problem. I am new to flutter and dart

Comment: https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables#filtering

Comment: i cant pass index + 1 in where statement. it shows an error

Comment: ooops, sorry, i messed you use that "next" item too... try removing `filteredSlots = ` from the loop

Comment: List<Slot> filterSlots() {
        filteredSlots = slotlist
            .where((index) => (index.isAvailable) & (index+1.isAvailable))
            .toList();
        return filteredSlots;
      }

Comment: i tried this but doesnt work because can use index+1

Comment: did you remove `filteredSlots =`  from the loop? just leave `filteredSlots.add(slotlist[i]);`

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

make   `bool isAvailable;` a static variable
`static   bool isAvailable;`